# Missing animation of UISlider width in custom table view cell when delete button appears

Tags: uitableview, animation, edit, uislider

This is a subtle problem: I have a custom tableview cell with a slider and a segmented control. When the table goes to editing mode everything looks good and when the red delete button appears, both the slider and segmented control shrink in width to leave room on the right for the delete button, and this shrink gets animated correctly. So all is good.

However, when the user does not go through with the delete and instead taps out of bounds, the slider immediately springs back to its full width before the delete button animation swipe finishes. The segmented control however is correctly animated back to its full width. I'm not handling any animation myself. Why is the slider not animating? My setup code is below. Any ideas?

Note that the animation for all the elements when the left side circular red selection button appears or disappears is just fine.

If I cannot fix this, I would like to know how to stop the delete button from pushing the content to the left when it appears, but retain the indentation animation for the selection button.

```
NSArray *itemArray = @[@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4"];
self.source = [[[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray] autorelease];
self.source.frame = CGRectMake(80, 10, cb.size.width - 92, 36);
self.source.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStylePlain;
self.source.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
self.source.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
[self.contentView addSubview:self.source];

self.phaseSlider = [[[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 50, cb.size.width - 92, 36)] autorelease];
self.phaseSlider.continuous = TRUE;
self.phaseSlider.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
[self.contentView addSubview:self.phaseSlider];
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the solution to this. Apparently there is some issue with using the resizing mask to allow the slider to resize when the delete button appears. Instead I removed the flexible width resizing masks. I initialize the controls in `initWithStyle` but only set the frame in `layoutSubViews`. This is actually the better way of setting the control frames anyway because the width and height of the cell is actually not known for sure in initWithStyle. When you set the frames in `layoutSubViews` it gets called during the delete button appear and disappear animation and the positions and sizes get animated correctly.

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self)
    {
        // Initialization code
        NSArray *itemArray = @[@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4"];
        self.source = [[[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray] autorelease];
        self.source.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStylePlain;
        self.source.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.source];

        self.phaseSlider = [[[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
        self.phaseSlider.continuous = TRUE;
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.phaseSlider];

        self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{    
    [super layoutSubviews];

    float w = self.contentView.bounds.size.width;

    self.source.frame = CGRectMake(78, 10, w - 92, 36);
    self.phaseSlider.frame = CGRectMake(78, 50, w - 92, 36);
}
```